# Insert field separator to arrange and capture value in variable in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a output which is not very well formatted and that causes the trouble in capturing variable value.

For example:

```
This is counter1 1000
this counter2 2000
this counter3 is higher value 3000
```

Now from above file I want to just capture 1000, 2000 and 3000. If I use awk with print $x where x = any value then it allocates the different values for each line. 
If I use $4 then for first line I will be able to select 1000 but for 2nd line it will not provide any value and for third line it will print higher so I want to insert the field separator and read the variable. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of `sed` are you using? Which OS?

Comment: I am running MAC OS 10.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want last argument, and only if a number:

```
echo $'For example:\nThis is counter1 1000\nthis counter2 2000\n
     this counter3 is higher value 3000\ndone.\n' |
  sed -ne 's/^.* \([0-9]\{1,99\}\)/\1/p'

1000
2000
3000
```

You could even trap the counter's number (and so read only line containing `counterX`):

```
echo $'For example:\nThis is counter1 1000\nthis counter2 2000\n
     this counter3 is higher value 3000\ndone.\n' |
  sed -ne 's/^.*\(counter[0-9]\{1,99\}\) \(.* \)\{0,1\}\([0-9]\{1,99\}\)$/\1 \3/p'

counter1 1000
counter2 2000
counter3 3000
```

Or even for just locating separator:

```
echo $'For example:\nThis is counter1 1000\nthis counter2 2000\n
     this counter3 is higher value 3000\ndone.\n' |
  sed -ne 's/^\(.*counter[0-9]\{1,99\}.*\) \([0-9]\{1,99\}\)$/\1 :: \2/p'
This is counter1 :: 1000
this counter2 :: 2000
this counter3 is higher value :: 3000
```

or, or...

```
echo $'For example:\nThis is counter1 1000\nthis counter2 2000\n
     this counter3 is higher value 3000\ndone.\n' |
  sed -e 's/^\(.*counter[0-9]\{1,99\}.*\) \([0-9]\{1,99\}\)$/\1 :: \2/'

For example:
This is counter1 :: 1000
this counter2 :: 2000
this counter3 is higher value :: 3000
done.
```

Comment: I tired sed -ne 's/^.* \([0-9]\+\)/\1/p' filename but that didnt work. i need to keep the description as well in output. If we can put the separator before the last value of digits then we can use $1 before separator and $2 after separator which will collect counter value.

Answer (score 5):

If the number is always the last field, you can do

```
{ print $NF }
```

Answer (score 1):

To print the last word, use

```
awk '{ print $NF }'
```

To separate words that are numbers, you can use

```
cat yourfile | tr ' ' '\n' | egrep '^[0-9]+$'
```

or the GNU specific `grep -ow '[0-9]*' yourfile`

To find only the first word that is a number on the line, you can use

```
awk '{ for(i=0; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~ /^[0-9]+$/) { print $i; break; } }'
```

Comment: The onliner you provided works fine if I have only "this is counter1 1000" but if I have "this is counter2 2000 1000" then it prints 2000 and 1000 both one after another, I want to get only 1000.

Comment: I updated the answer to find the first number on the line. Any more additional requirements?

Answer (score 0):

To print only the last element with sed, use something like this:

```
sed 's/.* //'
```

Test input:

```
cat << EOF > infile
This is counter1 1000
this counter2 2000
this counter3 is higher value 3000
EOF
```

Run test:

```
<infile sed 's/.* //'
```

Output:

```
1000
2000
3000
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way using sed

`sed -re 's/(.*)\s([0-9]+)/\2/' temp.txt`

Output

```
1000
2000
3000
```

Answer (score 0):

as other suggested you can use $NF in awk.
you can also use perl if at all the numbers are the last field always:

```
perl -F -lane 'print $F[scalar(@F)-1]' your_file
```

or in case its not always the last field, then:

```
perl -F -lane 'for(@F){print if(/^\d+$/)}' your_file
```